# Apache Conditional Proxy pass

Tags: apache, .htaccess, proxypass

I don't have much experience with servers. So, this might be a stupid question.Currently in my Apache server vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file, I have a proxypass as below.

```
    ProxyPass        /phpmyadmin !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

I want to implement a conditional proxy pass for below scenario

if the URL contains `?_escaped_fragment_=`, like the URL below

```
http://localhost/web/?_escaped_fragment_=/health
```

I want this URL to be redirected to a URL with a different port like the URL below,

```
http://localhost:8082/web/?_escaped_fragment_=/health
```

if the URL doesnt contain `?_escaped_fragment_=`, like the URL below,

```
http://localhost/web/#!/health
```

The proxy pass I mentioned earlier which redirects to port 8080 should happen. What is the code for this?

Comment: What is the apache version?

Comment: Searching for [apache conditional proxypass](https://www.google.de/search?q=apache+conditional+proxypass) gives among others http://serverfault.com/questions/625426/how-to-create-conditional-proxypass, maybe this helps.

Comment: Hi, My apache version is Apache/2.4.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ProxyPass can't go inside a If statement you will need to use mod_rewrite to proxy/redirect and use a RewriteCond to filter the query string.

Since query string does not change as it was requested, here is a rough example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8082/$1 [QSA,P,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8082/
```

Which means, if query_string matches the string "_escaped_fragment_WHATEVERHERE" proxy everything to destination at port 8082 and append whatever query string it was added.

For other cases proxy it will proxy to localhost:8080.

Note that I added QSA which is a flag that says append any query string in original request, but I added it for clarity shake, since mod_rewrite will do it anyways by default in this case. More info about it in the rewrite flags link I add bellow.

You can make this example be much more specific, for example last rewrite will take any other query string, if you don't want that you could filter it out with a more detailed rewritecond earlier or with another rewritecond.

For more details here is what the official docs say about it:
[Rewrite Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)
[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: I've used this king of a rewrite rule. But I cant implement this because then the URL in browser also will automatically change to localhost which doesnt work with my implementation. I want the URL in the browser to be the same. Cant I use IfDefine to check the condition and define the port number. I've tried doing this and It doesnt work. And when I tried Defining a variable inside if, it gives an error.

Comment: If you add an example on when the page returns as http://localhost or similar, then I may be able to help. These rewrites do not affect the hostname in the url at all, and the issue you describe has nothing to do with them, you are just probably missing a ProxyPassReverse entry, as in, add: `ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/` and `ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8082/`. Let me fix the answer to add those.

Comment: @ezra-s, I want do something like `RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse /$1 http://localhost:8080/`

I want to add matched text in `RewriteRule` to `ProxyPassReverse`.
How can I do it?

Comment: "ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/" matches every possible url-path sent back by backend in a redirect so you don't need anything like you describe.